# Stop App Maker creating duplicate relations

Tags: duplicates, relational-database, google-app-maker

When I change the relations between two data sources using a Multi Select widget, App Maker duplicates the relations.

**Exported data:**

[image: Duplicate relations]

The **product - bundles** relation is many-to-many.

This relation is managed from the **product** data source via a Multi Select widget for the **bundles**.

Multi Select settings:

- Data source: **product** (inherited).
- Values: bound to `@datasource.item.bundles`.
- Options: bound to `@datasources.bundles.items`.

Has anyone encountered this before, discovered why, or found a solution?
I have tried Googling anything I can think of to find a solution, but I have not found anyone else with this issue.

I have observed this in more than one of my relations that are managed by a Multi Select widget. I have also observed this in one of my relations that are managed via a client-side script that is triggered in the UI (but I'm going to assume I am at fault on that one until I find out why the Multi Selects make duplicates).

Documentation I have read to try to understand why:

[Modify associations with a data binding](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/relations#data_binding) *i.e Multi Select widgets*

[Many-to-many export](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/import-export#many-to-many)

---

#### **EDIT**

Logging the related records to the console shows that while I'm editing the relations, there is only one instance of each record. After saving the **product** record and reloading the app, logging to the console shows that both relations have been duplicated.

Also, the **product** data source is in manual-save mode and the **bundle** data source is not.

Comment: I set up an environment equal to what you described. After testing, so far I am not having any issues. The items are related without any duplicates. So unless there is something that we are not seeing (custom logic on your end), I believe this should be a bug on your end.

Comment: Thank you @Morfinismo. I think it has to do with the fact that one of the data sources is in manual-save mode and the other is not. I have changed the data source that was in manual-save mode to auto-save mode and I haven't had this issue since. I'm just going to wait a few days before adding this as the answer, just to make sure it's not a fluke. Thanks again!

Comment: Not really, I have one data source in manual save mode (product) and the other is not. So that is no the problem for sure.